# Send message to all telegram bot members

Tags: php, telegram-bot

I wrote a telegram bot with php . I want to send a text to all Members, I saved all members chat_id.
I tried to send message with this function :

```
function sendMessage($chatId, $message) {

    $url = WEBSITE . "/sendMessage?chat_id=" . $chatId . "&text=" . urlencode($message);
    file_get_contents($url);
}
```

and use this function for get user chatid and send message:

```
public function sendall($message) {
        $sql = $this->con->prepare('SELECT * FROM `users`');
        $sql->execute();
        $res = $sql->fetchAll();
        foreach ($res as $row) {
            sendMessage($row['chatid'], $message);
        }
        exit();
    }
```

But this is not working correctly and the message is sent to members several times and it does not stop until I clear my database.

Comment: Does your table users have unique chat_id for each user?

Comment: @Aman yes chat_id is unique

Comment: can you share a dump of users table along with its schema ? (A couple of rows will suffice)

Comment: here image of database :  http://uploads.im/vR4I9.jpg
http://uploads.im/tZIsP.jpg

Answer (score 1):

The API will not allow more than ~30 messages to different users per second, Answered  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42076098/4293142).

Answer (score -1):

This url send bot message select chat id user,

https://api.telegram.org/bot-token/sendMessage?chat_id=xxxx&text=yyy

Comment: OP is aware of that as visible in the line where they put together the URL as string (`$url = WEBSITE . "/sendMessage?chat_id=" . $chatId . "&text=" . urlencode($message);`). This does not answer as to why the issues occur with messages being sent several times.