# sendMessage to any bot user

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I have a server bot (made with cronjobs and PHP): if a condition is met, the bot sends a mail containing a specific message. I noticed any person receiving the mail message has a Telegram account too. What I want to do is the following: I create a bot and, instead of sending mails, the bot posts the message users generally receive by mail.

I tried the following using the command line:

```
curl -s -X POST https://api.telegram.org/botToken/sendMessage -d text=”hello from the bot” -d chat_id=0000000
```

My bot receives the message but what I don't understand well is: will this message reach ANY other bot user?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

due to [Bots FAQ](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#how-can-i-message-all-of-my-bot-39s-subscribers-at-once/) in telegram website :

> **How can I message all of my bot's subscribers at once?**
>   Unfortunately, at this moment we don't have methods for sending bulk messages, e.g. notifications. We may add something along these lines in the future.

Answer (score 0):

sendMessage will send a message to a user specified by unique identifier **chat_id**.

Keep in mind that a bot can't initiate a conversation with a user. Users must contact a bot first in order to receive any messages by the bot.

Comment: So, you're suggesting I should retrieve and store the chat_id of a user when the user first posts

Comment: Or you just let the bot post to a private channel. Might work for you.